# CodeIgniter 1.7 reCaptcha Help

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha, recaptcha

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/ReCAPTCHA/

Okay. So I download the code. Move all the files to the appropriate folders. Set the keys in the config/recaptcha.php file. Then where I have my form submit logic I put in the

```
$this->form_validation->run()
```

function.

Then in the HTML I do what?? I need to display the captcha for user input. I see google's code for adding the php recaptcha into non-code igniter documents, but I'm not sure which parts of that are relevant. And I'm not sure how I'm supposed to be making calls to particular files. Right now

```
<? $this->load->view('recaptcha.php'); 
$publickey = "thekeynumbersandgibberish"; 
echo get_html($publickey); 
?>
```

this currently breaks my HTML page, I figure I'm not calling the file and function correctly using code igniter syntax. What is the proper syntax? This was not included in the code igniter documentation.

Insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't used the recaptcha in CI, but when using it with cake, I just loaded the captcha html using `$captcha = recaptcha_get_html($publickey);` in the controller and then assigned it to the view. Didn't load any files in the view

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really know all the finer details that entails. Can you elaborate? How exactly would I "assign something to a view"

Comment: I've added some more details as an answer.

Comment: Also have a look at the sample that is included

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this in your controller first

```
//In your Controller
$data['recaptcha']  = this->recaptcha->get_html();
$this->load->view('my_view',$data); //try it with the test page first

//In your View
$this->load->view('recaptcha.php');
```

The instructions in the wiki are pretty straightforward. Don't load the files in the view. Assign the HTML in the controller.

This is the normal process when working on MVC.

There's a basic CI tutorial here : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-basics/

Comment: Thank you, this has so far been very helpful. I have one file contact.php where my contact form is, `<?=$this->load->view('recaptcha.php');?>` is placed in the correct place, I can see the code has loaded when I do a view source. It doesn't show visually though, I haven't done the part for the controller yet because I cant find a controller that "this->load->"s the contact view. I'm practically reverse engineering this file structure trying to figure this out, I think a CMS was used to create this site but I don't know which CMS/how to find out based on just having a directry listing

Comment: Well, you've mentioned Codeigniter. So just look at the URL. Usually, the urls are crafted like this `http://sitename.com/controller/action/param`. This is the standard, unless custom routes are involved. You might have to speak to someone who's familiar with the project to find out. Because if you're using a templating engine, the view call will be different

Comment: the URL path looks like `http://sitename.com//folder/deeperfolder`  first of all is this something you recognize? secondly it is completely custom, and yes there are two slashes following the site name. Where would that be defined? I get the basic CodeIgniter MVC stuff but this extra twist doesn't seem to have anything intuitive in the directory structure

Comment: Have a look at the `application/config/routes.php` file. That has all the routes. Figure out which controller is being called in your action.

Comment: I just have `$route default_controller = 'main'` so I went throw every file in the controllers directory searching for a main class. No luck. I also have noticed some files are looking for controller/cms.php which does not exist, and also some functions extend CMS  `if (file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/cms.php')) include_once(APPPATH.'controllers/cms.php');
else include_once(RESPATH.'controllers/cms.php'); `  and that file doesn't show up in my directory listing at all. the plot thickens.

Comment: Well, without physically being able to access your project I'm at the end of my tether. You'll need to speak to the person who managed the project till now :(